# Python RotatingFileHandler doesn't seem to be rotating the logs

Tags: python, logging

I had setup a logger with the following code:

```
log = logging.getLogger('base')
logfilename =  <path to logfile>
logFile = logging.FileHandler(logfilename)
log.setLevel(debug)
logFile.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s]: [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d:%(funcName)s]: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s', datefmt='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
log.addHandler(logFile)
```

Since the log files were large, I wanted to create a rotating log file.
Hence I made the following change:

```
# logFile = logging.FileHandler(logfilename)
logFile = RotatingFileHandler(logfilename, maxBytes=1024)  # maxBytes=1024 only for testing
```

However, the resulting log file isn't rotated. I still get logs that are few MBs large. I have cleared all the `.pyc` files.

Questions:

1. Is it necessary to specify the backup count (I need to retain all logs! Hence if this is mandatory, I have to give some insanely large number).
2. By `maxBytes` I assume it is actual Bytes (so in my case log should be rotated every 1 kB) and nothing else. Am I correct?
3. Is there a minimum number for `maxBytes` below which rotating is ineffective? (I suppose not)

I work with Python 2.7.14 (Anaconda) and 3.6.4 (Anaconda).

Comment: "but if either of maxBytes or backupCount is zero, rollover never occurs, so you generally want to set backupCount to at least 1, and have a non-zero maxBytes." -- from official doc.

Comment: And there is no way to enable infinite backup count. -- from source code. So maybe you can simulate it by setting a huge backup count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `backupCount` value, *or* change the file mode from appending to truncating on open.

The log file *is* closed, but then *re-opened again for appending*, so you never actually see a difference.

What happens now is:

- The handler tests if the current file length plus the message pushes the file length over the maximum.

  - If the length is over the maximum, close the file
  - If `backupCount` is greater than zero, rotate any existing backup files, and then rename the log file to add `.1`
  - Open the logfile for appending. If there already is a file there with the same name, then that file is re-opened.
- Write the message to the open log file.

Apart from setting `backupCount` to a number higher than 0, you could also change the `mode` parameter to `'w'`, at which point you'll find that the file is *truncated* each time it would get too large:

```
# 'rotate' logfile by truncating:
logFile = RotatingFileHandler(logfilename, mode='w', maxBytes=1024)
```

Note that the file can still become larger than `maxBytes`, if the new message itself is greater than 1024 bytes long.

There is no option to retain *all* rotated files. You'd indeed have to use an insanely high number, *or* use a different file rotation strategy. For example, the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` rotates files after a given interval, and if you leave `backupCount` at zero, it'll never delete rotated backups.

You could also subclass `RotatingFileHandler()` to implement your own renaming strategy, providing your own `doRollover()` method. You need to generate unique names if you want to retain all backups; you could add a UUID to ensure this (together with the date):

```
import uuid
from datetime import datetime
from logging import RotatingFileHandler

class InfiniteRotatingFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    def doRollover(self):
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        new_name = '{}.{:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}.{}'.format(
            self.baseFilename, datetime.now(), uuid.uuid4())
        self.rotate(self.baseFilename, new_name)
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()
```

Comment: Setting the mode to 'w' did not make any difference, however setting the backupCount helps. For now, I have set backup count to some large value.

Comment: @okkhoy: I offered better alternatives, however.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html):

> if either of maxBytes or backupCount is zero, rollover never occurs,
>   so you generally want to set backupCount to at least 1, and have a
>   non-zero maxBytes.

Which means that without setting `backupCount` (the default value is 0) you don't get any rollover functionality

> I need to retain all logs! Hence if this is mandatory, I have to give
>   some insanely large number

Yes! Set some insanely large number, and maybe add another script to backup old files every once in a while

Comment: I have another script to backup old logs in place. This requirement is due to a "quirk" (for lack of better word) to describe the necessity.